# Is SFINAE forbidden in template arguments, or did I hit a clang bug?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, sfinae

What follows is a simplified version of a problem I hit with real code.

**Short version**: just look at the code and error at [gcc.godbolt.org](http://goo.gl/NGYL1U) / long version: read on ;)

Suppose I want a class with a template parameter `setting` and a method `int func(int)` such as:

- when `setting` is `false`, `func` returns its argument
- when `setting` is `true`, `func` doubles its argument

The simplest way to do that is to specialize the class template:

```
template<bool setting> struct A {
    int func(x) const { return 2 * x; }
};
template<> struct A<false> {
    int func(x) { return x; }
};
```

The problem with this approach is that if I have a bunch of other methods that don't depend on `setting`, I'll have to copy-paste them in both specialization (or inherit from a common base, when there's not too much inter-dependencies).

So instead, I can use SFINAE to select the right method, e.g. with `std::enable_if`. This requires the method to have a template argument, because substitution failure must invalidate just the method, not the whole class. As far as I know, the failure can occur in either of:

- a method's argument type
- the method's return type
- a template parameter type

Here's the code using the method's arguments:

```
template<bool setting> struct B {
    template<bool when=true>
    int func(int x
            , typename std::enable_if<when && setting>::type * u=0
            )
    { return 2 * x; }

    template<bool when=true>
    int func(int x
            , typename std::enable_if<when && !setting>::type * u=0
            )
    { return x; }
};
```

And here's the version using the method's template arguments:

```
template<bool setting> struct C {
    template<bool when=true, typename std::enable_if<
              when && setting
            >::type...>
    int func(int x) { return 2 * x; }

    template<bool when=true, typename std::enable_if<
              when && !setting
            >::type...>
    int func(int x) { return x; }
};
```

I tend to prefer the last version, as it makes the method's signature more readable, but that's a matter of personal taste.

My question concerns this last version: is it valid C++ ? gcc compiles it fine, but clang does not (tested with `-std=c++11` / `c++1y` / `c++1z` with same results). The class definition in itself compiles OK, but the error occurs when it's instantiated:

```
int main() {
    A<true> a;
    B<true> b;
    C<true> c;
    return a.func(1) + b.func(2) + c.func(3);
}
```

compiles in gcc 5.3 but not with clang 3.7.1:

```
test.cpp:30:36: error: call to member function 'func' is ambiguous
                return a.func(1) + b.func(2) + c.func(3);
                                            ~~^~~~
test.cpp:20:7: note: candidate function [with when = true, $1 = <>]
                int func(int x) { return 2 * x; }
                    ^
test.cpp:23:7: note: candidate function [with when = true, $1 = <>]
                int func(int x) { return x; }
                    ^
1 error generated.
```

So is this valid C++ ? Is it a clang bug or is gcc wrong in accepting this code ?

Comment: Note that you may specialize only the methods to specialize, not the whole class.

Comment: Replacing `...` by `* = nullptr` works: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b883edb6a0fce779)

Comment: @Jarod42: Nice, thanks! While it solves my practical problem, I'm still wondering if the `...` version is valid C++ ?

Comment: And [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/263e3920072592f1) for my first comment.

Comment: @Jarod42: Indeed, but that precludes inlining.

Comment: You may still inline the specialization.

Comment: I would say that `...` version may be related to [CWG 1558](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1558).

Comment: Seems like it. So it used to be undefined behaviour, but my class `C` might become valid with C++17 ? You may want to post that as an answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is SFINAE forbidden in template arguments

It is valid. You may do for example:

```
template<bool setting> struct C {
    template<bool when=true, typename std::enable_if<
              when && setting
            >::type* = nullptr>
    int func(int x) { return 2 * x; }

    template<bool when=true, typename std::enable_if<
              when && !setting
            >::type* = nullptr>
    int func(int x) { return x; }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b883edb6a0fce779)

The problem with `typename std::enable_if<when && !setting>::type...` should be related to [CWG 1558](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1558).
And so your code should be correct in C++17.

Comment: That one is not CWG 1558 - it has nothing to do with alias templates. It's a plain Clang bug. Also, this isn't technically valid. For every value of `setting`, one of the two overloads is ill-formed NDR because no valid specialization can be generated for it.

Comment: The clang problem is fixed by http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20160201/148893.html